# How to improve tesseract ocr results on a clear image?

Tags: ocr, tesseract

I have compiled tesseract 5.0.0-alpha from source,
and have tried all different Page segmentation modes.
I know in advance the actual font is written with font **DejaVu Sans Mono**,
So I have trained the model with this font (maxpages = 600), and eventually generated the model.

but for some reason tesseract misses. for example, here is a simple image after it was preprocessed:

[image]

But I keep getting wrong values, the letter l is getting replaced with the digit 1.
and an actual space between digit 6 to letter l is getting ignored/disappeared.
Can someone give me some suggestions?

Thank you all,
I deeply appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 with tesseract version 5. I use below command and got the correct result. Maybe you can try the same command.

```
tesseract HfUmN.jpg stdout -l eng --oem 3 --psm 7 -c tessedit_char_whitelist="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789=[], "
Warning: Invalid resolution 0 dpi. Using 70 instead.
6 l1 = [1, 2, 4, 5]
```

```
tesseract --version
tesseract 5.0.0-alpha-647-g4a00
 leptonica-1.78.0
  libgif 5.1.4 : libjpeg 8d (libjpeg-turbo 1.5.2) : libpng 1.6.34 : libtiff 4.0.9 : zlib 1.2.11 : libwebp 0.6.1 : libopenjp2 2.3.0
 Found AVX2
 Found AVX
 Found FMA
 Found SSE
 Found OpenMP 201511
 Found libarchive 3.2.2 zlib/1.2.11 liblzma/5.2.2 bz2lib/1.0.6 liblz4/1.7.1
```

Comment: Interesting cause I'm getting a different result:                                                             

611 =[1, 2, 4, 5]   

I have checked it now with the original model eng.traineddata posted on github, how can it be?
The only different is i'm using leptonica-1.75.3, tesseract 5.0.0-alpha-648-gcdebe with the same Ubuntu version.

Comment: Sometimes tesseract give different result. I do not know the inner working.